# PostGIS geocoding with local street centerline data

Tags: postgis, geocoding, tiger

I have the [PostGIS TIGER geocoder](https://postgis.net/docs/Extras.html) setup and working to geocode addresses in a single city. I am trying to use local [street centerline data](https://catalog.data.gov/dataset/nyc-street-centerline-cscl) for geocoding instead of the TIGER data because it is more complete.

The linked PostGIS documentation briefly mentions that the geocoding function could be altered and applied to other data sets.

What approach would I need to take to alter the PostGIS geocoding function to use a different data set?

Answer (score 2):

I would use the tiger geocoder as a backup and create your own geocoder using OpenAddresses.io data and full-text search in postgres.